# Add Style attribute to HTML tags from code behind using C#

Tags: c#, html, styles, code-behind

[image]

Hi all,

I want to add style attributes in my HTML tags using C#. Please find the below code.

```
            StringBuilder mailBody = new StringBuilder();
            mailBody.AppendFormat("<html>");
            mailBody.AppendFormat("<p>Please note:</p>");
            mailBody.AppendFormat("<p> " + data + " folder no longer exists on the network. Please review at your earliest convenience. </p>");
            mailBody.AppendFormat("<br/>");
            mailBody.AppendFormat("<p>Thank you</p>");
            mailBody.AppendFormat("<p>Development Team</p>");
            mailBody.AppendFormat("</html>");
            emailBody = mailBody.ToString();
```

**And the output is :**

The text displayed in the image font style is "Time New Roman". How could I change that to display in any other font type. How could I add that in above HTML tags.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p><span style="font-family:Verdana">Please note:</span></p>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp

Comment: Hi Tim, It worked when I made a small change in the tag like this. Thanks for the answer. :) 

<p><span style=font-family:calibri;>Please note:</span></p>

Answer (score 2):

Add the style to the tag, like this:

```
<p style="font-family:courier">Please note:</p>
```

Check for more info here: http://w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
   <p style="font-family:arial black">Please note:</p>
```

pls go through this link for more info

http://w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp

Answer (score 0):

An even easier way would be to put it in the CSS

```
BODY P
{
}
```

Then you wouldnt need to put it into all the P tags

Or if you want to make it only apply to a section
You should surround this in a div and then

```
.<DivClassName> P
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this, so you're taking advantage of CSS:

```
var mailBody = new StringBuilder();

// put in the font(s) you'd like to use. If font 1 isn't installed,
// it will move on to the next font in line, and so forth.
var font = "Arial, Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif";

// the color of the text. If you'd like to use more colors, take
// advantage of CSS classes.
var color = "red";

mailBody.Append("<html><head>");
mailBody.Append("<style type=\"text/css\">");
mailBody.AppendFormat("body { font-family: {0}; color: {1}; }", 
        font, color);
mailBody.Append("</style>");
mailBody.Append("<p>Please note:</p>");
mailBody.AppendFormat("<p>{0} folder no longer exists on the network. Please review at your earliest convenience.</p>", 
        data);
mailBody.Append("<br/>");
mailBody.Append("<p>Thank you</p>");
mailBody.Append("<p>Development Team</p>");
mailBody.Append("</html>");
emailBody = mailBody.ToString();
```

Also note, you don't need to use the AppendFormat method unless you plan on passing in parameters into the tokens embedded in the string (`{0}`, `{1}` etc).